# При нумерации слов в консоль пишет ошибку

Tags: javascript

Реализовал логику на JS, пронумеровал каждый `<p>` таким образом:

```
const numberParagraph = document.querySelectorAll('.conteiner p');

for (let i = 0; i <= numberParagraph.length; i++) {
    const numberText = i + 1;
    numberParagraph[i].innerHTML = numberText + '. ' + numberParagraph[i].innerHTML;

}
```

В консоли пишет ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')

Нумерация работает, но после этой ошибки дальнейший код не работает.
В чём может быть причина? Помогите плиз!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся причина в вашем условии `i <= numberParagraph.length` в цикле `for`. Здесь не нужно "меньше или равно", здесь нужно только "меньше". Т.к. нумерация массива начинается с `0`, а `numberParagraph.length` возвращает КОЛ-ВО элементов. Это число будет больше, чем максимальный индекс в массиве.

Comment: Спасибо, неожиданно и элементарно просто получилось)